# Berkley packet filter for Windows

Tags: windows, sniffing

Is Berkley Packet Filter supported on Windows or is there something comparable which I should use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For windows there is [WinPCap](http://www.winpcap.org) that could help you do the same thing.
On XP SP2 and Vista there is the limitation that only administrators can create raw packets.

More info about Berkeley Packet Filter [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_Packet_Filter)